# How come <a> tag does not produce a clickable link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a link that looks like this:

```
<p class="half_text"><?php echo $upvotes; ?> <strong>
<a id="vote_up" style="color: #295B7B; font-weight:bold;" href="">Vote Up</a>
</strong> | <?php echo $downvotes; ?> <strong>
<a id="vote_down" style="color: #295B7B; font-weight:bold;" href="">Vote Down</a>    
</strong></p>
```

and some jQuery code that I am trying to get called.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#vote_up').click(function() 
{
    alert("up");
});
</script>
```

But for some reason the alert does not fire when the vote up or down links are pressed.  Any idea what I am doing wrong?

You can see this for yourself here: http://www.problemio.com

Comment: To start, change your vote_up and vote_down to classes. You should only have one instance of an id on a page and I'm guessing jquery isn't grabbing the one you want.

Comment: Among the other problems mentioned (so far they all look relevant), you also need to `return false` from the `click` event handler to prevent the page navigation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to place your code inside the `.ready()` handler:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#vote_up').click(function() 
    {
        alert("up");

        //Return false to prevent page navigation
        return false;
    });
});
```

Take a look at the `.ready()` docs: http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Here's [a working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesHill/GghFH/).

Comment: Minor addendum, but I'd set href="#", add "e" as an argument to the anonymous function and then call `e.preventDefault()`.  Doing this removes the need for `return false` in the function.

Answer (score 4):

Wrap your code in a `.ready()` handler. The shortcut is `$(function(){...})`:

```
$(function(){
   $('#vote_up').click(function() {
      alert("up");
   });
})
```

is equivalent to `$(document).ready(function(){....})`.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if it's necessary but try putting a `#` in the `href` attribute.

Also, you are using `id` attributes for your links when there are more than one of each on the page, you should use `class` instead.

Comment: No need for the `href` attribute: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.2

Comment: @davin actually without the href attribute it wasn't making the text into a link. Would you know why that was happening?

Comment: @Genadinik, `href` is the location. Without a location to point to, it doesn't really link anywhere, so the browser doesn't render it as a "link" per se. Although that's just for styling aspects, the standard still considers it valid markup.

Answer (score 2):

The `id` attribute is supposed to be unique across a document.  If you want it to apply to multiple elements, consider using a `class` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is causing your problem but you have duplicate ids on your page.

Try changing 'vote_up' and 'vote_down' to classes.